# Setting up a log-in for a website using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have to create a website with the sole purpose of connecting to a MySQL database and displaying its information in a graphical user interface.

So far everything is working well. My problem, however, is setting up some sort of log in system to get the user's `$username` and `$password`.

While the website is being developed for LAN use I would rather not put a `username` and `password` in HTML or PHP for security reasons.

How would I go about writing code to ask the user for a `password` and `username` on my index page, have it used for all of the other pages on my site, and ultimately have it forgotten when the user closes my website? At the moment I only know HTML, CSS, and some very naive PHP.

Comment: Hy u will have to go through some tutorials. [here is one](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html). Also search in youtube there are nice and easy tutorials for login system. and also search for PHP session, hope this helps you.

Comment: Your question is too general. You should research this topic and attempt to solve the problem on your own; if there is a specific issue that you are unable to resolve in the process, come back and present it and we can help you out.

Comment: Haha sorry, I'm pretty new to this. I'll look around and see if I can't get a more specific question for you guys. Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/

Comment: @Dave please dont advice tutorials with outdated and deprecated content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a nutshell:
login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
function hhb_tohtml($str)
{
    return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);
}

$accounts=array(
//username =>password
'smith'=>'smell',
'admin'=>'password',
'guest'=>'guestpass'
);

if(array_key_exists('submit',$_POST)){
    if(!array_key_exists('username',$_POST)){
        $username='';
    } else 
    {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    }
    if(!array_key_exists('password',$_POST)){
        $password='';
    }else {
        $password=$_POST['password'];
    }
    if(!array_key_exists($username,$accounts)){
        die('This username does not exist.');
    }
    if($accounts[$username]!==$password){
        die('wrong password!');
    }
    $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    die('you have logged in as: '.hhb_tohtml($username));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<form action="?" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and in other places, like controlpanel.php:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){die('you need to login first!');}
```

the session id will be stored in a cookie, thanks to session_start(), and the server will remember whether or not this session id is logged in.

Comment: When the session data is getting stored in a cookie, user can change `logged_in` to true and login without password.. not a secure solution.

Comment: The cookie is just a identifier for the server. The information is on the server, not on the client !

Comment: @DanFromGermany you're completely wrong. $_SESSION is only stored on the SERVER. it is associated with the user by a cookie looking like PHPSESSID=485a67891ffd01d4836863015ee7fa38

Comment: You might be right on 99% of the internet's servers, but not all session handlers work the same. Some save the DATA in the Cookie, not only the identifier.

Comment: @hanshenrik See: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler

Comment: you just stored this in the PHP. Take it end-to-end, the whole thing, and tell him how to do it secured. You are about 35 to 40% done with an answer

Comment: put in a missing `?>` that was causing a `Server Error 500`. When the user closes the browser tab, will still be logged in, according to `SESSION`, and I wonder what the question above has anything to do with mysql whatsoever (at least with this answer). Which is simply the risk one gets in when answering very broad questions. Like going down with the Titanic

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you would be able to use the standard type of login using a session. There are many tutorials to show you how to achieve this and there are many different ways to get to the outcome. It all depends on your skills, level of safety and database requirements, to name a few.

You should start by having a look at a tutorial like this which makes use of a session http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/ this will give you the "forget password" functionality. Unless a user saves the password using their browser.

Just in case the tutorial above is not to your liking here a a few more:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php14p2.html
http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

and my personal favorite http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_login_example.htm

I hope you find something to help you, if you have any issues implementing one of these examples please post a question with your code for someone to help you resolve it.